# Function throwing eslint.org guard-for-in error

Tags: javascript, eslint

Using this for loop to build a querystring with no issues.

```
  for (const key in parameters) {
    const value = parameters[key];
    qs += `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(value)}&`;
  }
```

Until now I notice ESLint red lining.  The documentation says the following:

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/guard-for-in

```
/*eslint guard-for-in: "error"*/

for (key in foo) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(foo, key)) {
        doSomething(key);
    }
}

for (key in foo) {
    if ({}.hasOwnProperty.call(foo, key)) {
        doSomething(key);
    }
}
```

~

Comment: Only trolls down vote without giving a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap the code inside the for loop like this

```
for (const key in parameters) {
    if (!parameters.hasOwnProperty(key)) { continue; }
    const value = parameters[key];
    qs += `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(value)}&`;
}
```

`parameters.hasOwnProperty(key)` this check if the property/key exists in the object `parameters`

but that's still probably not what you want as it eslint now says: `for..in loops iterate over the entire prototype chain, which is virtually never what you want. Use Object.{keys,values,entries}, and iterate over the resulting array.eslintno-restricted-syntax`

### As suggested there, this lints clean:

```
  Object.keys(parameters).forEach((key) => {
    const value = parameters[key];
    qs += `${encodeURIComponent(key)}=${encodeURIComponent(value)}&`;
  });
```

Comment: I've edited your answer instead of self answering so that I could award you the 'karma' points. Iterating over the entire prototype chain wasn't desirable in this case.